# Excel formula to make dynamic links

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

How to create dynamic hyperlinks to urls, for example I have the following data I want to create hyperlinks in cell A based on the value of cell B, note that the url changes everytime and the number of rows also changes

[image]

What I know is the static way of creating them but how to make it dynamic?

Comment: Put the formula
     =HYPERLINK(B3,"URL") in cell A3, so whenever URL changes in B3 hyperlink for "URL" in cell A3 will also change, I think this is what you mean by dynamic.

Comment: that I know, but the range in A cell will differ as the data in the excel sheet is connected to an external data source, so it will change every time, i want something dynamic. like everytime i'm pulling new data, Cell A links will update according to cell B values @Ethun_Hunt

Comment: Put your data in a table, switch your column A and B, so when you will add an entry in the column A, the table will expand and your formula in B will follow